# undefined method `search' for Twitter:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I'm learning mongodb with ruby, I write update.rb as follows:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'
require 'twitter'

require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config')

class TweetArchiver
  def initialize(tag)
    connection = Mongo::Connection.new
    db = connection[DATABASE_NAME]
    @tweets = db[COLLECTION_NAME]

    @tweets.create_index([['id', 1]], :unique => true)
    @tweets.create_index([['tags', 1], ['id', -1]])

    @tag = tag
    @tweets_found = 0
  end

  def update
    puts "Starting Twitter search for '#{@tag}'..."
    save_tweets_for(@tag)
    print "#{@tweets_found} tweets saved.\n\n"
  end

  private
  def save_tweets_for(term)
    Twitter.search(term).each do |tweet|
      @tweets_found += 1
      tweet_with_tag = tweet.to_hash.merge!({"tags" => [term]})
      @tweets.save(tweet_with_tag)
    end
  end
end
```

I run ruby update.rb, then get error:

> undefined method `search' for Twitter:Module (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite self-explanatory. The `Twitter` module has no `search` method defined.

```
Twitter.search(term).each do |tweet|
```

You should check the documentation of the library to make sure you are using it in the right way.